# Show empty folders

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have this script

```
for /d %%i in (*) do @dir /b /s /a-d "%%i">nul 2>&1|| @echo "%%i" has no files
```

pause
but it only shows empty folders in the same directory how can i change it to show the empty folders level below

Comment: `FOR /D /R` should work.

Comment: Thanx that worked fine, just to understand something when i use the for/d in (*) it serach in the current directory what is the command to ask to search in one level down in a tree or 2 levels down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for /d /r %%i in (*) do @dir /b /s /a-d "%%i">nul 2>&1|| @echo "%%i" has no files
pause`
this command works